How do I check whether the sanitizer is enabled at runtime?
I have unit tests that verify all sorts of things. For example, it checks whether I can send a SIGUSR1 to the process and the process does what it is expected to do when receiving that signal.
This works as expected. Nearly no issue there, except that when compiled with the sanitizer some other function (ppoll() in my case) receives an interrupt. This is because when I create threads, I turn off many signals. Some of which either the sanitizer and/or catch2 are using. What I need is for my lower level library to not mess around with those signals.
The following is the list I've found to work (not commented) and cause issues (commented out). The SIGKILL is not an issue, but there is really no point in trying to ignore that signal. The signals with number 32 and 33 are used internally and cannot be tempered with if you don't want to break the pthread implementation (at least under Linux).
// SIGHUP, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
// SIGINT, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGQUIT,
// SIGILL, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGTRAP,
// SIGABRT, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGBUS,
// SIGFPE, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
// SIGKILL, -- cannot be ignored
SIGUSR1,
// SIGSEGV, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGUSR2,
SIGPIPE,
SIGALRM,
// SIGTERM, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGSTKFLT,
SIGCHLD,
// SIGCONT, -- cannot be ignored
// SIGSTOP, -- cannot be ignored
//SIGTSTP, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGTTIN,
SIGTTOU,
SIGURG,
SIGXCPU,
SIGXFSZ,
SIGVTALRM,
// SIGPROF, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGWINCH,
// SIGIO, -- not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer
SIGPWR,
SIGSYS,
// 32 -- used by pthread implementation
// 33 -- used by pthread implementation
SIGRTMIN,
SIGRTMIN+1,
SIGRTMIN+2,
SIGRTMIN+3,
SIGRTMIN+4,
SIGRTMIN+5,
SIGRTMIN+6,
SIGRTMIN+7,
SIGRTMIN+8,
SIGRTMIN+9,
SIGRTMIN+10,
SIGRTMIN+11,
SIGRTMIN+12,
SIGRTMIN+13,
SIGRTMIN+14,
SIGRTMIN+15,
SIGRTMAX-14,
SIGRTMAX-13,
SIGRTMAX-12,
SIGRTMAX-11,
SIGRTMAX-10,
SIGRTMAX-9,
SIGRTMAX-8,
SIGRTMAX-7,
SIGRTMAX-6,
SIGRTMAX-5,
SIGRTMAX-4,
SIGRTMAX-3,
SIGRTMAX-2,
SIGRTMAX-1,
SIGRTMAX,

I'd like the signals marked with "not compatible with catch2 and/or sanitizer" to be removed from the list only if the unit test is running with the sanitizer. However, when I compile the library handling those signals, it may not itself be compiled with the sanitizer. So when I link against it, at the moment, it has no clue whether we have the sanitizer or not. The only way I've found is to use #ifdef and such at compile time:
#if defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__) || defined(__SANITIZE_THREAD__)
... code when sanitizer is activated in this process ...
#endif

What I would need is a test in my code, something like:
if(sanitizer_is_running())
{
    ...remove breaking signals from my list...
}

Do you know of a way to implement this sanitizer_is_running() function which has to work at run time?

I found a way that works, but I think it's rather ugly. Hopefully someone can come up with a cleaner solution.
The fact is that if linked against the sanitizer library, the functions defined in the library will be accessible. That means we can search for one of those symbols and if present, we know that we are running with the sanitizer.
#include <dlfcn.h>

...

if(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "__lsan_enable") != nullptr)
{
    // ... here we know that the sanitizer is active ...
}

I tested and it works in my environment, a.k.a. on Linux. It may also work on other Unix systems.

This method may fail if libasan-rt (or whatever provides __lsan_enable symbol) is linked into the main binary as an archive library.


However, when I compile the library handling those signals, it may not itself be compiled with the sanitizer.

Note that in general you should instrument all the code. Sanitizers are progressively less effective as you exclude more code from instrumentation.


I found a way that works, but I think it's rather ugly.

A less ugly way is to compile this function into your main program:
int sanitizer_is_running()
{
#if defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__) || defined(__SANITIZE_THREAD__)
  return 1;
#else
  return 0;
#endif
}

and use that from your library.

Yeah, using all the libraries with the sanitizer would be ideal. I already use those defines in several places. I have an environment where all my libraries are compiled with the sanitizer. It's just much slower so in most cases I run in _DEBUG and only use the current library/tools with the sanitizer.
